# How can I use all the cores in the loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, c++17

There is a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    //...
    v[i] = o.f(i);
    //...
}
```

Each `v[i] = o.f(i)` is independent of all the other `v[i] = o.f(i)`.
`n` can be any value and it may not be a multiple of the number of cores. What is the simplest way to use all the cores to do this?

Comment: Try `tbb` library.

Comment: msvc. But I want to make crossplatform code.

Comment: @Ufx: Is `v[i] = o.f(i);` expensive enough to be *worth* the overhead of farming them out to other cores and then synchronizing the results? If not, then don't bother.

Comment: With c++11 [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) is an easy way of parallelizing jobs.  With c++17 you can provide run [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with an [execution policy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t).

Comment: @Ufx tbb is pretty cross platform

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux MSVC `std::async` is sadly far from standard compliant, at least as of 2015.  I am uncertain if they fixed everything in 2017, I got burned twice and stopped using it.  (it had incorrect destruction behavior, and it used a global thread pool, both of which cause serious problems)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I would prefer standard library if it's possible.

Comment: @Ufx Those are all features from the standard library. If by "standard" you mean c++03, it's not more or less standard than c++11 and c++17, simply different versions of the language. When people talk about standard c++ without specifying the version, it's usually assumed to mean the most recent standard published.

Comment: @Nicol I suspect the cost is inside o.f(i), not the assignment of the result.

Comment: OpenMP does exactly this, and most compilers (GCC, LLVM, MSVC) support it. By adding a line like `#pragma omp parallel for` over the `for` loop.

Answer (score 6):

The [`ExecutionPolicy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) overloads of the algorithms in `<algorithm>` exist for this purpose. [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) applies a function to each element of a source range to assign to a destination range.

`v.begin()` is an acceptable destination, so long as `v` is of appropriate size. Your snippet assumes this when it uses `v[i]`, so I will too.

We then need an iterator that gives the values `[0, n)` as our source, so [`boost::counting_iterator<int>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html).

Finally we need a `Callable` that will apply `o.f` to our values, so lets capture `o` in a lambda.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

// assert(v.size() >= n)
std::transform(std::execution::par, boost::counting_iterator<int>(0), boost::counting_iterator<int>(n), v.begin(), [&o](int i){ return o.f(i); });
```

If `o.f` does not perform any "vectorization-unsafe operations", you are able to use [`std::execution::par_unseq`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t), which *may* interleave calls on the same thread (i.e. unroll the loop and use SIMD instructions)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I dunno, it says "something like".  That isn't code.

Comment: Since each call is independent, could probably use `std::execution::par_unseq` policy.

Comment: @user2079303 I just added some advice on that.

Answer (score 4):

In the land of existing compilers, and remembering that M/S can't even get this stuff right for C++11, never mind about C++17/20, the C++11 answer goes something like:

```
typedef v.value_type R;
std::vector< std::future<R> > fut(n);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    fut[i] = std::async(std::launch::async, O::f, o, i);
for (auto& f : fut)
    v.push_back(f.get());
```

@arne suggests we can do better by throttling the number of tasks by considering the number of processors (P), which is true, though the above code will give you a clear indication on whether you will really benefit from multi-threading the method f. Given we only want to launch X jobs simultaneously, where X is > P, < 3*P depending on the variation in job complexity (note I am relying on a signed index):

```
typedef v.value_type R;
std::vector< std::future<R> > fut(n);
for (ssize_t i=0, j=-X; j<n; i++,j++)
{
    if (i<n)    fut[i] = std::async(std::launch::async, O::f, o, i);
    if (j>=0)   v.push_back(fut[j].get());
}
```

I'm not claiming the above code is "great", but if the jobs are complex enough for us to need multithreading, the cost of looping a few extra times isn't gointg to be noticed. You will notice that if X > n the loop will spin a few times in the middle, but will produce the correct result :-)

Comment: This spawns a thread for each invocation, which may be very inefficient. I suggest breaking the work down into chunks of `n / std::this_thread::hardware_concurrency()`, if the latter does not return zero (if it does, a sensible default value should be used instead).

Comment: Yes there are many ways to make it use the resources better, but as a first step it will show you if there is any benefit to be gained. There are issues with batching and waiting if your jobs are not all similar sized. Another way to drive the processor load balancing is to launch the first X jobs, then launch 1 job at a time as you wait for the first already launched job to finish, then finally wait for the last X jobs to finish.